# If zip file and folder name are identical, copy zip file into folder

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, process

I have many .zip files and folders some of them have identical names.
I will check zip file name and folder name if it is identical.
I will copy zip file into the folder and delete the zip file.

Is it possible to Automate the process?

I have found following code but couldn't edit it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd "C:\New folder"
FOR %%G IN (*.zip DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%a IN ("%%G") do (
        set "outFolder=%%a Random Center"
        for /D %%i in (*.*) do (
            for /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%b IN ("%%i") do (
                if "%%a"=="%%b" set "outFolder=%%i"
            )
        )
        if not exist "!outfolder!" md "!outfolder!"
        move "%%G" "!outfolder!"
    )
)
popd
pause
```

It creates *Random Center* folder and copy all the zip files in it which I don't want.

Comment: is this windows batch script? You need to add more tags relating to language and os.

Comment: Yes os: Windows , I need a batch or vbs script , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

pushd "C:\New folder" || exit /b 1

for %%A in (*.zip) do if exist "%%~nA" (
    pushd "%%~nA" && (
        move /y "..\%%~nxA"
        popd
    )
)

popd
pause
```

Using `move` as see no need to
`copy` and `del` the zip file.
Argument `/y` will automatically
overwrite an existing file without
prompt.

Initial `pushd` changes the current directory
else exits with `errorlevel` 1.

The `for` loop iterates through each zip filename.
It checks if the name of the filename, without extension,
does exist, which is expected to be a folder.
If does exist, `pushd` into the directory, and then
`move` the zip file from the parent directory into
the current directory. `popd` will restore to the
previous directory.

Does final `popd` to restore to initial current directory.

Comment: Exactly what I want  , solved my problem , thank you very much